# Android NDK "Hello From C++" App Gives Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I installed `Android NDK`,`LLDB` and `CMake` from `SDK Manager` after that I created a new project with C/C++ support in Android Studio.I didn't change anything and I run the project and I got error.

I got this error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/NdkWorkPlaces/nativeapp1/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3: error: resource 'attr/android:font' has invalid entry name 'android:font'. Invalid character 'android:font'.
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/NdkWorkPlaces/nativeapp1/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:4: error: resource 'attr/android:fontStyle' has invalid entry name 'android:fontStyle'. Invalid character 'android:fontStyle'.
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/NdkWorkPlaces/nativeapp1/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:5: error: resource 'attr/android:fontVariationSettings' has invalid entry name 'android:fontVariationSettings'. Invalid character 'android:fontVariationSettings'.
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/NdkWorkPlaces/nativeapp1/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6: error: resource 'attr/android:fontWeight' has invalid entry name 'android:fontWeight'. Invalid character 'android:fontWeight'.
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/NdkWorkPlaces/nativeapp1/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7: error: resource 'attr/android:ttcIndex' has invalid entry name 'android:ttcIndex'. Invalid character 'android:ttcIndex'.
```

I can't try anything for solve this problem. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the `compileSdkVersion 28` to `compileSdkVersion 27` , `targetSdkVersion 28` to `targetSdkVersion 27` and  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` in `build.gradle(Module:app)` file.

But still, I don't know why it doesn't work in the sdk version 28.

Comment: Support library version has nothing to do with NDK